# ¿Es "millionarismo" una palabra válida?

Tags: palabras-raras

He visto la palabra "millionarismo" mencionada algunas veces y usando el traductor de Google la traduce al inglés como "millionarism". Pero parece una palabra inventada, y varias veces la escriben con comillas. ¿Es una palabra correcta o un término inventado para salir del paso en alguna explicación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay muchas instancias de la palabra *millionarism* en internet. La más frecuente y posiblemente la más antigua es [de William D. Howells](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=RKxkAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT32&ots=JoL0QKdMHT&dq=what%20is%20millionarism&pg=PT32#v=onepage&q=millionarism&f=false) en una crítica a los poemas de Emily Dickinson en 1891. Aparece en textos más modernos e incluso en foros de discusión, pero no en los diccionarios a los que puedo acceder. Parece significar "veneración del estilo de vida de los millonarios (personas muy ricas en dinero)" o "aspiración a convertirse en millonario".

En cualquier caso no existe en castellano, pero si fuéramos a adoptar la palabra, lógica y analógicamente debería ser como *millonarismo* (con *-llo-*, no con *-llio-* como en inglés). Por el contexto debería ser claro su significado. Queda a criterio del lector si inventar neologismos de esta manera funciona en cada caso.

Comment: Yo lo entiendo como el estilo de vida del millonario. Más allá de si estilo de vida es bueno o malo.